# Advanced resetting forms with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, field, reset

When you try to register and you keep something blank/not filled in, you get an error. (from PHP). The input fields where something has been filled in stay remembered ( Smarty: `{if isset($smarty.post.registratie.naam)} value="{$smarty.post.registratie.naam}"{else}value="Naam:"{/if}`)

Problem: After the unsuccessful registration attempt, the default value of my input fields that was first "Naam:","Voornaam:","Email:" has been changed to the value that the user has put in. (For example "Frederik")

Example: http://www.pixsters.be/index.php?page=registratie

With my Jquery code i clear the fields where there is a default value, although i don't want to clear the fields that have been filled in by the user.

Jquery code:

```
function clearField(e)
{
    if($(this).val() == this.defaultValue)
    {
        $(this).val('');
    }

}

function resetField(e)
{
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's wrong with the current code? Other than that, you could simply use just `<input placeholder="Naam:">` for modern browsers.

Comment: Well if you want to retype something (after a first submit) in a previous field (if you wrote your name wrong or something) the value dissapears. And then the whole point of remembering the value to edit it afterwards is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the new page is loaded, the inputted values have become the `defaultValue`s. Instead, you could use the `placeholder` attribute (there are also some plugins for older browsers):

```
<input placeholder="Naam:" ...>
```

This will automatically take care of disappearing when typing something without any JavaScript, and it doesn't suffer from your issue.

You probably want to keep it black, though:

```
/* add other prefixes if necessary */
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad interface design idea to hide field titles. At some point user will not be able to tell what some fields are for. Consider to change the design.

If you still want to stick with it just add default values to the input fields, e.g.:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" data-default-value="Enter your name:" name="name" value="{$form.name}">
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Iterating through all form elements.
    $.each('#my-form input[type="text"]', function() {
        // Adding event listener and calling it afterwards to fill the inputs initially.
        $(this).change(function() {
            var $Input = $(this);
            // If element value is not set (empty), then using default value.
            if ($Input.val() == '') {
                $Input.val($Input.attr('data-default-value'));
            }
        }).change();

    });
});
```